# Keras Custom Function Problem for Sequential Model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, nonlinear-optimization

I have recently started building Neural Networks and I am currently working on a project to develop a NN for Van der Pol's equation. My problem is that I developed a sequential model with time and mu as inputs. But my loss function is custom (because I needed to compute derivatives etc) and it requires additional external custom parameters (2 arrays of input data and one scalar), which change based on input data.

My question is that, I have trained my model, but before predicting, I have to update these loss function parameters (external ones), so do I use model.compile before predicting? Because I have read alot and from what I assume, it degrades the performance of the trained model. Is there any other way to achieve this? please help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Keras ValueError: Dimensions must be equal - How to pass label-dependent values to custom loss function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62154660/keras-valueerror-dimensions-must-be-equal-how-to-pass-label-dependent-values)